# When to use lookup field?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

Whenever I'm considering the option of making a field's contents being extracted from a predefined list, should I make a new table to list exclusively those options, then make a query, then make a form-level lookup field to select it?

This seems like creating A LOT of tables and queries from those tables, just to have a lookup field. I have no idea what the normal number should be, or if there is a clever way of doing queries without creating new tables everytime that I'm not aware of.

For example: I have an Addresses table, and each address can be of three types: home, professional, other. Should I make a table exclusively to list those items and then reference it through a query and a lookup field in a form?

What's the procedure here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't you just have a column in your `Addresses` table called `Address_Type` and only allow the input of one of those three options you had mentioned?  I think that there almost certainly is a misunderstanding about something here, I don't think I have ever wrestled with the idea of having a lookup field.

Comment: There's plenty of misunderstanding hahaha . I'm a complete newbie in the databases. So... how do I limit the choices without creating a lookup field? Through a Validation Rule maybe?

Comment: I generally do my validation on the input form itself.  In your scenario I would likely use a combobox with only the three types as an option.

Comment: But... :S I still don't get it. What constitutes a lookup field then? I see everywhere that I should not use them. I thought a ComboBox was a type of lookup (after all, in the design view in Access, the way to select Text Box, List Box or Combo Box is through the LOOKUP tab in the Field Properties). What makes a Combo Box not a Lookup Field?

Comment: The combobox I am speaking of would be one you just put on a form and manually set the values.  I think the kind you are thinking of is when you are directly on a table and you set the Rowsource of a field to be a query.  Something like [this](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-a-lookup-field-87e84cbd-d60c-4473-8a98-3e391c42f239).  If you were to build a combobox using the second method then every time you load a form with that field on there the query the drives the combobox would run.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use table lookup when you are going to use this lookup in another entity or you are going to allow the end-user to edit entries of this lookup. In other cases, be free to confine yourself to use constant list of values.

Feel free to ask more.

Comment: It's rude to downvote an answer without any comment. I improve answers with pleasure when I am asked.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. Since values won't change later (even when in hands of the end-user) I'll stick to form lookups and not table lookups I think. (did I say that right?)